Is there an extension of the digit sum function to real numbers?
Is there a known way to extend the base $b$ digit sum function $s_b(\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}d_i b^i)=\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}d_i$ to a smooth function on the real numbers similarly to how one can extend the factorial function to complex numbers with the Gamma function?

You can just choose the values between the integers to be some arbitrary smooth curves with matching derivatives at the endpoints, but there's not any point to doing this. The Gamma function is not important because it extends the factorial, it's important because it frequently comes up in practice when evaluating all sorts of integrals, in a way that often generalizes the appearance of a factorial.

For what purpose?  Divisibility testing?  (Which makes sense for rationals, but not for arbitrary reals.)

If you want to preserve the most useful properties of the digit sum function, $Q(10x) = Q(x)$ and $Q(x) \equiv x \pmod{9}$, you can't.

@Dan For the purpose of analyzing a certain map that maps integers $q\in{1,...,n(b-1)}$ to $s_b(qM)$, where $M$ and $n$ are some numbers. In particular, I'm interested in the fixed points of this map.

Not in a nice or useful way.
We can always extend a function on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to a smooth function on all of $\mathbb{R}$ if the first function's domain contains only isolated points. But this is very unconstrained and can involve some arbitrary choices, and the values at other points don't need any relation.
(Notice given $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$, and $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus X$, if $X$ contains only isolated points, so does $X \cup \{x\}$, so we can choose any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and likewise extend $f$ to a smooth function $\tilde f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\tilde f\!(x) = y$. That is, looking at just one point $x$, $\tilde f\!(x)$ could be anything at all.)
So what is a property of $s_b$ we would like its extension to preserve? One simple property is that for any non-negative integer $n$, $s_b(bn) = s_b(n)$. But no function $f : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{C}$ can have these three properties:

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(n) = s_b(n)$
$f$ is continuous.
For every $x \in (0,\infty)$, $f(bx) = f(x)$

Proof: Suppose $f$ does satisfy all three properties. Let $x_0=1$ and $\epsilon=\frac 12$. Then if $f$ is continuous, there is a real $\delta>0$ so that $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. That is, $0 < |x-1|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-1| < \frac 12$. Let $k$ be a positive integer so that $k > -\log_b \delta$. Then $b^{-k} < \delta$, and
$$ f(1+b^{-k}) = f(b^k(1+b^{-k})) = f(b^k + 1) = s_b(b^k + 1) = 2 $$
But $0 < |(1+b^{-k})-1| < \delta$ and $|f(x)-1| = 1 > \frac 12$. Contradiction; $f$ cannot satisfy all three properties.

I don't understand what you mean by ”if the original domain has no limit points". Is that what you meant to say?

@MJD As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point , if that helps. Actually, I guess "has no limit points" is equivalent to "contains only isolated points".

I understand now. I think it would be clearer to say something like "if the original domain is a closed set".

@MJD Not the same: we can't extend a discontinuous function on $[0,1]$ to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks for the recent edit.  I see now that I didn't understand what you meant.
